# Log http requests in db table with django and tastypie without increase response time

Tags: django, logging, push-notification, tastypie, get-request

I have android app on which my django server is sending some push notifications using firebase cloud messaging. As soon as client received the notifications, it makes a GET request to my API written using Tastypie.

I want to somehow store this GET request in my Log table so that I can ensure that my android app is working fine and make right requests on receiving notifications from server.

On one of the answers, I read that it can be achieved by overriding the dispatch function for Model Resource in tastypie. Could this logging be achieved without overriding the dispatch because it can potentially increase the response time.

Comment: Saving requests to the database would be an intensive way to store information that isn't that useful. For storing request data, do you know have access logs setup by your server? Apache/Nginx log to files, but you can use a service like Graylog to do this as well; https://www.graylog.org/

Comment: I have access logs setup already but since I need to make ensure that against each notification, there is a GET request for which I need to maintain it in DB such that notifications that have no GET requests can be fired again.

Comment: Then why not just have an object in the database linked to the user, then when they hit that view set a field value like `has_loaded_view = True` then save the object.